# Programmatically resolving Maven dependencies outside of a plugin - get RepositorySystemSession and RepositorySystem

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, aether

Maybe this is going to be a larger task than I had originally thought, but regardless, I'm trying to load a `MavenProject` from a file and then resolve its dependencies. I've got the code for both bits but I'm missing some object references that I need; specifically I need to get instances of  `RepositorySystemSession` and `RepositorySystem`. Any tips?

*Note:* I have tagged this question with [maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-plugin), but this is not a Maven plugin. I am happy to mandate Maven 3 (think I already have anyway..)

Here's the code I have so far:

**Constructing the `MavenProject`**:

```
public static MavenProject loadProject(File pomFile) throws Exception
{
    MavenProject ret = null;
    MavenXpp3Reader mavenReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

    if (pomFile != null && pomFile.exists())
    {
        FileReader reader = null;

        try
            {
            reader = new FileReader(pomFile);
            Model model = mavenReader.read(reader);
            model.setPomFile(pomFile);

            ret = new MavenProject(model);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close reader
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**Resolving dependencies:**

```
public static List<Dependency> getArtifactsDependencies(MavenProject project, String dependencyType, String scope) throws Exception
{    
    DefaultArtifact pomArtifact = new DefaultArtifact(project.getId());

    RepositorySystemSession repoSession = null; // TODO
    RepositorySystem repoSystem = null; // TODO

    List<RemoteRepository> remoteRepos = project.getRemoteProjectRepositories();
    List<Dependency> ret = new ArrayList<Dependency>();

    Dependency dependency = new Dependency(pomArtifact, scope);

    CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
    collectRequest.setRoot(dependency);
    collectRequest.setRepositories(remoteRepos);

    DependencyNode node = repoSystem.collectDependencies(repoSession, collectRequest).getRoot();
    DependencyRequest projectDependencyRequest = new DependencyRequest(node, null);

    repoSystem.resolveDependencies(repoSession, projectDependencyRequest);

    PreorderNodeListGenerator nlg = new PreorderNodeListGenerator();
    node.accept(nlg);

    ret.addAll(nlg.getDependencies(true));

    return ret;
}
```

I realise this might be an unusual request, maybe I should just scrap what I was trying to do and wrap it as a plugin...but I kind of just want to finish what I started now! Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Aether examples](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to read the information about [Aether lib](http://www.eclipse.org/aether/) which is exactly is for such kind of purposes.

Note: Aether was previousely developed at Sonatype, but has since moved to [Eclipse](http://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-aether).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer although I still feel the documentation is a little light...I can get the `RepositorySystem` now based on the documentation, but creating a `RepositorySystemSession` with all of the same Maven settings is still proving a little tricky. I've checked out the _maven.settings.building_ package as the documentation suggests but to no avail. Ideally I don't want to specify everything, I want my _pom.xml_ file (and settings.xml) to be the source of all information. I think my current issue is that `project.getRepositories()` is null..I'll keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look into this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/pom-interpolator-test (it's created enhanced from an Aether example).

Comment: Thanks again, useful bits of code but apparently I just get exception after exception using code snippets from the example. This is too much hassle for something that'll most regularly get run inside a plugin. If I have time later I'll come back to it, thanks again anyway.

Comment: Sorry to say that but the documentation on http://www.eclipse.org/aether/ is very poor. Nearly not existing. When can we expect a good documentation?

Comment: Aether is back on Apache again: https://projects.eclipse.org/comment/208#comment-208

Answer (score 5):

Try [jcabi-aether](http://aether.jcabi.com/), which is a wrapper around [Apache Aether](http://www.sonatype.org/aether) from Sonatype:

```
final File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
final Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

If you are outside of Maven plugin:

```
final File repo = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "my-repo");
final MavenProject project = new MavenProject();
project.setRemoteArtifactRepositories(
  Arrays.asList(
    new RemoteRepository(
      "maven-central",
      "default",
      "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    )
  )
);
final Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(project, repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - the library does look interesting but I'm still left with no `RepositorySystemSession`, unless I'm inside of a plugin execution :(

Answer (score 4):

I just whipped up a solution to both your and my problem:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2013 TerraFrame, Inc. All rights reserved. 
 * 
 * This file is part of Runway SDK(tm).
 * 
 * Runway SDK(tm) is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the
 * License, or (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * Runway SDK(tm) is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
 * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with Runway SDK(tm).  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 ******************************************************************************/

package com.test.mavenaether;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryPolicy;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.MavenArtifactRepository;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.DefaultRepositoryLayout;
import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;
import org.sonatype.aether.artifact.Artifact;
import org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException;
import org.sonatype.aether.util.artifact.DefaultArtifact;
import org.sonatype.aether.util.artifact.JavaScopes;

import com.jcabi.aether.Aether;

public class MavenAether
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String classpath = getClasspathFromMavenProject(new File("/users/terraframe/documents/workspace/MavenSandbox/pom.xml"), new File("/users/terraframe/.m2/repository"));
    System.out.println("classpath = " + classpath);
  }

  public static String getClasspathFromMavenProject(File projectPom, File localRepoFolder) throws DependencyResolutionException, IOException, XmlPullParserException
  {
    MavenProject proj = loadProject(projectPom);

    proj.setRemoteArtifactRepositories(
        Arrays.asList(
            (ArtifactRepository) new MavenArtifactRepository(
                "maven-central", "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/", new DefaultRepositoryLayout(),
                new ArtifactRepositoryPolicy(), new ArtifactRepositoryPolicy()
            )
        )
    );

    String classpath = "";
    Aether aether = new Aether(proj, localRepoFolder);

    List<org.apache.maven.model.Dependency> dependencies = proj.getDependencies();
    Iterator<org.apache.maven.model.Dependency> it = dependencies.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
      org.apache.maven.model.Dependency depend = it.next();

      final Collection<Artifact> deps = aether.resolve(
        new DefaultArtifact(depend.getGroupId(), depend.getArtifactId(), depend.getClassifier(), depend.getType(), depend.getVersion()),
        JavaScopes.RUNTIME
      );

      Iterator<Artifact> artIt = deps.iterator();
      while (artIt.hasNext()) {
        Artifact art = artIt.next();
        classpath = classpath + " " + art.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
      }
    }

    return classpath;
  }

  public static MavenProject loadProject(File pomFile) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
  {
      MavenProject ret = null;
      MavenXpp3Reader mavenReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

      if (pomFile != null && pomFile.exists())
      {
          FileReader reader = null;

          try
              {
              reader = new FileReader(pomFile);
              Model model = mavenReader.read(reader);
              model.setPomFile(pomFile);

              ret = new MavenProject(model);
          }
          finally
          {
            reader.close();
          }
      }

      return ret;
  }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenSandbox</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcabi-aether</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The code first loads the Maven project (using your function provided in the original question), then uses jcabi-aether to find the artifact in your local repository. You will need to change the two parameters in the main function: the location for the pom.xml of your project, and the location of your local repository.

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (as can be seen from the [ather-demo](https://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-aether/blob/master/aether-demo/src/main/java/demo/util/Booter.java)):

```
...
LocalRepository localRepository = new LocalRepository("/path/to/local-repo");

RepositorySystem system = getRepositorySystemInstance();
RepositorySystemSession session = getRepositorySystemSessionInstance(system, localRepository);
....

public static RepositorySystem getRepositorySystemInstance()
{
    /**
     * Aether's components implement org.sonatype.aether.spi.locator.Service to ease manual wiring and using the
     * prepopulated DefaultServiceLocator, we only need to register the repository connector factories.
     */
    MavenServiceLocator locator = new MavenServiceLocator();
    locator.addService(RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, FileRepositoryConnectorFactory.class);
    locator.addService(RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory.class);
    locator.setServices(WagonProvider.class, new ManualWagonProvider());

    return locator.getService(RepositorySystem.class);
}

private static RepositorySystemSession getRepositorySystemSessionInstance(RepositorySystem system,
                                                                          LocalRepository localRepo)
{
    MavenRepositorySystemSession session = new MavenRepositorySystemSession();

    session.setLocalRepositoryManager(system.newLocalRepositoryManager(localRepo));

    session.setTransferListener(new ConsoleTransferListener());
    session.setRepositoryListener(new ConsoleRepositoryListener());

    // Set this in order to generate dirty trees
    session.setDependencyGraphTransformer(null);

    return session;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice set of standalone examples for Eclipses Aether API which is used in the latest Maven (3.1.1) and it can be found [here](https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/blob/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/ResolveTransitiveDependencies.java).

Note: Maven 3.1.X still uses Aether `0.9.0.M2` (and the latest version which us used in the examples is `0.9.0.M3`). So to run these examples inside a Maven plugin, version M2 is required, and a standalone application can use the latest M3 version.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in ["Aether/Setting Aether Up"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Setting_Aether_Up) for the RepositorySystem and in ["Aether/Creating a Repository System Session"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Creating_a_Repository_System_Session) in the eclipse wiki.

There is not a ton of documentation, but you can create a RepositorySystem as follows:

```
// verbatim copy from the Setting Aether Up link
private static RepositorySystem newRepositorySystem()
{
    DefaultServiceLocator locator = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
    locator.addService( RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class );
    locator.addService( TransporterFactory.class, FileTransporterFactory.class );
    locator.addService( TransporterFactory.class, HttpTransporterFactory.class );

    return locator.getService( RepositorySystem.class );
}
```

Do note that this requires the dependencies detailed in ["Getting Aether"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Getting_Aether), most notably `maven-aether-provider`.

When you have your repository system the tutorial goes on to create a RepositorySystemSession with the following factory method:

```
// copied verbatim from "Creating a Repository System Session"
private static RepositorySystemSession newSession( RepositorySystem system )
{
    DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();

    LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository( "target/local-repo" );
    session.setLocalRepositoryManager( system.newLocalRepositoryManager( session, localRepo ) );

    return session;
}
```

Comment: First real answer here so far. So sad it is outdated and no longer works.