# APIs for maven dependency

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

Are there any API that helps to find dependency of maven packages.
I used the examples present in the answer of [Programmatically resolving Maven dependencies outside of a plugin - get RepositorySystemSession and RepositorySystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799923/programmatically-resolving-maven-dependencies-outside-of-a-plugin-get-reposito)

However the dependency list that I get using aether is different from the list given by APIs

AFAIK. The API did not resolve ranges, I am not sure whether it handles exclusions.

Is there any readily available API that takes care of resolving version ranges, exclusions (simillar to what i get when using "mvn dependency-list/tree)

I am looking for API that exactly returns result provided by mvn dependency:list/tree

Note: My code is running outside mvn plugin

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use two tools:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

This tool provides effective pom - the very detailed pom.xml with all actual dependencies and versions

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Provides the dependency tree