# API to get dependency tree of a maven dependency

Tags: api, maven

Is it possible to get the dependency tree or list of dependencies of a given maven dependency using an API?

Comment: Do you need this inside a Maven plugin or inside a Java program?

Comment: Inside a Java Program

Comment: Why do you need it inside a java program what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to download all the dependent packages of a given maven dependency (eg: `org.apache.commons.commons-lang3.3.9`) to a specific folder. Is there any API provided by Maven to do that?

Comment: Have you thought about just calling the maven dependency plugin? It is a command line call, but it is a direct way to achieve this. From Java, you could try to use Maven Resolver (Aether).

Comment: Alright, So there is no such an API to achieve this directly?

Comment: Maven Resolver is such an API, but I cannot provide you a concrete example.

Comment: @JFMeier Can you please provide some kind of example or link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11799923/927493

Comment: @JFMeier Can you suggest to me a way that I can list down all the dependencies of a mvn project programmatically without using CLI? Can I use maven dependency plugin to do that?

Comment: Sorry to be so unspecific, but I know that you _can_ do such things with Maven Resolver or Aether (as it was called before). But I do not know any good source or tutorial for it. There are examples on Stackoverflow, scattered at various places.

Comment: BTW: What is the reason you want to copy these dependencies?